# dbt schema cleanup in Snowflake

Tags: continuous-integration, snowflake-schema, dbt

When we create Pull Requests in GitHub it auto triggers a dbt cloud job that runs a test build of our models.  The database in Snowflake for this build is called "Continuous Integration".  In this database we have hundreds of schemas going back almost 2 years.  Is there any reason to keep these schemas and tables?  I sure would like to do some cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete these old schemas with no consequence.

Each of these schemas is built based on the change introduced in an earlier version of the code & (depending on how you set up your github action) either using a pre-defined test data or the raw data available at the time of the test begin run.

These CI jobs can serve two use-cases.

1. [primary] test the code works & data validation tests pass
2. they can act as a way to do time travel, which I'll describe below.

The first use-case does not need the artifact to be preserved after once the job runs

The second use-case may be important to you in trying to debug reports that were generated many months ago.

Example: lets say the finance department wants to know why a historical value of active users has changed in the latest report. this may have been an error that was fixed within your dbt logic, or perhaps the active users was pulled with an incorrect filter from your BI layer, if you had dbt artifacts built from that era, you would be able to use it to look for any dbt level changes.

How far back do you think you'd need the artifacts for time travel? Check with your stakeholders and come up with a time frame that works for your business, and you can delete all the CI artifacts built prior to that date.